# While loop for two conditions to be checked simultaneously in array form?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a while loop for the following statement in python:

I have a vector valued function which returns a 2x1 array with x and y values

I want to write a code that ensures the loop is only run when the [x,y] given by the function are less than [x,y]

I tried to use a.all() however getting an attribute error

Is there another way to check two conditions simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that the `array` in your code is `np.array`.

Let's define the data `a`, `b` and `c`.

```py
a = np.array([[3], [2]])  #[[3], [2]]
b = np.array([[2], [1]])
c = np.array([[4], [1]])
```

If we do the following comparison, we will obtain

```py
In [1]: a > b
Out[1]:
array([[ True],
       [ True]])

In [2]: a > c
Out[2]:
array([[False],
       [ True]])
```

Since you want to ensure both conditions to be true at the same time, you can use the python built-in `all()`, which returns True only if all of the parameters are true.

```py
In [3]: all(a > c)
Out[3]: False

In [4]: all(a > b)
Out[4]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either like this:

```
while all(abs(val) > err for val, err in zip(f(x, y), a):
    ...
```

Or like this:

```
while abs(f(x, y)[0]) > a[0] and abs(f(x, y)[1]) > a[1]:
    ...
```